# Why are all of my git submodles not being cloned when I do git clone --recursive?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I tried to export my emacs and vim configurations into their own repositories, and added them as submodles to a superrepository.  However when I try to do

```
git clone --recursive
```

to clone the superrepository, it only pulls in the ext/rsense submodule and ignores the other two.  What am I doing wrong?  I am using git 1.7.0.4

Here's the .gitmodules for my superrepository

```
[submodule "vim"]
        path = vim
        url = https://github.com:sid137/.vim.git
[submodule ".emacs.d"]
        path = .emacs.d
        url = https://github.com:sid137/emacs.git
[submodule "ext/rsense"]
        path = ext/rsense
        url = https://github.com/m2ym/rsense.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question as

[Git will not init/sync/update new submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336995/git-will-not-init-sync-update-new-submodules)

I just removed my .gitmodules and readded them manually also using

```
git submodule add repo local_path
```

and it mysteriously worked