# Adding git submodules automatically (.gitmodules)

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo with several submodules. I want to add some others, and the fastest way for me is to use the `.gitmodules` (which in my opinion should clearly allow any kind of submodule management).

However, when editing this file and adding submodules, after a `git submodule init` nothing is added (except the submodules that were already present before the modification).

Is there any solution to add a submodule without going through `git submodule add` (ie, just by editing the `.gitmodules` file and then `git submodule update --init`) ?

That is, the following workflow should automatically add the submodule "*foo/bar*":

```
Add the following to .gitmodules:
    [submodule "foo/bar"]
        path = foo/bar
        url = https://example.com/foo.git

Run the following command after saving:
    git submodule init
    git submodule update

Expected result:
    submodule 'foo/bar' automatically gets added
    it is also updated (the update command)
```

Comment: When you write `git submodule add` its simply adding the new entry to the .submodules files, so what you described is correct and it should work for you. this is why after the `add` you have to run `init & update`

Comment: Not using `git submodule add` results in the module not being added for me (sadly)... When you think about it, git is able to track thousands of modifications in a lot of files, but totally lost when it comes to 3 added lines in `.gitmodules`...

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your update, you cannot do it manually unless you know how to create the module directory under `.git` folder.

Comment: execute this command and view the results `GIT_TRACE=2 git submodule add git@github.com....`

Comment: Quite crazy this is not possible in a text-oriented tool like this ^^

Answer (score 5):

When you add a Git submodule, Git creates `.gitmodules` file and for a submodule named `git-submodule` will add something like this:

```
[submodule "git-submodule"]
    path = git-submodule
    url = https://github.com/TomasHubelbauer/git-submodule
```

The same is added to `.git/config` after the existing content in that file.

A folder for the submodule named after the submodule is created in `.git/modules`.
This folder is nearly identical to the the `.git` directory of the actual submodule repository, but it doesn't contain the actual `objects` (instead the submodule data is checked out to its directory and its metadata are here).

This means that theoretically, you might be able to add a submodule by hand without using `git submodule add`, but you would have to recreate all these config files.
But one can still imagine cloning the submodule repository to a separate directory and copying its `.git` over to this one. That *might* work.

However, adding a submodule also changes the index, `.git/index`, so you would have to manually update this hash as well, and at this point, you're reimplementing Git, but manually.

As a result, I don't believe it is anywhere near practical to add a Git submodule by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question was not really about how to add a submodule by hand though, it was about how to make the `.gitmodule` file the *master* of the submodule configuration, that is you edit it and type `git submodule update` to adjust the repo. Apparently, this is not possible :(

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood that. I also wish that was the case!

Answer (score 2):

Yep, as you described once you add submodule its being added to your `.gitsubmodule` file.

But unless you know exactly what you do its much better to use the CLI command since there might be something that you not familiar with like:

Once you done editing your submodule file you will need to run:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Adding it manually will not work.

Run the add submodule and watch the `.git` folder changes. You will see a new folder named `module` with your submodule name.

This is why you should not do it manually.

Comment: Well, my question is not adding by using the command line. What I would like is `git submodule init` to automatically add non-staged modules that are present in gitmodules. Ie, that the gitmodules files dictates how git manages submodules (and not the inverse). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's established that Git manages `.gitmodules` but does not read new entries from it, here is a oneliner in case it can be helpful to anyone else facing this problem.

It goes through the `.gitmodules` file looking for lines starting with `[whitespace]url =`  and executes `git submodule add` followed by the URL that follows. It assumes that you want to create submodules with the same names as the corresponding repositories.

```
cat .gitmodules | sed -n 's/^\s*url = \(\S*\) */git submodule add \1/p' | bash
```

Explanation:

```
cat .gitmodules          # output file content
sed -n                   # output only the relevant lines
's/regEx/replacement/p'  # print the 'replacement' of the 'regEx'
^\s*url =                # look for lines starting with [whitespace]url = 
                         # but not, e.g., with #[whitespace]
\(\S*\) *                # capture all characters, ignore trailing [space] 
git submodule add \1     # append the captured URL to the git command
bash                     # execute the command
```

Omit the `| bash` part to only print the commands without executing them. Modify the git command to your liking. After successful execution, you can do `git submodule update --remote` to checkout the branches/revisions that may be specified in `.gitmodules`.