# git submodule sync doesn't work

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to change the remote on a submodule as per [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405542/1402368).

After modifying and saving `.gitmodules`, then doing `git submodule sync` my submodule hasn't changed, though my `.git/config` file has been updated to match the new remote url in `.gitmodules`.

I've also tried `git submodule sync --recursive`, and doing `rm -rf .git/modules/<mySubmodule>` as per [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404704/how-do-i-replace-a-git-submodule-with-another-repo#comment30543163_14405542) without any difference. In fact, running the latter command then `git submodule sync` again gives `fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/<mySubmodule>`. Any tips?

I initially added the submodule to the project via `git submodule add git://<mySubmodule-url>` as per the [git docs](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

**Edit**

I've even updated git via homebrew to v2.1.1, still nothing. I've also tried starting completely from scratch, and even switching between two completely different submodules but I'm still getting the same results. In sum:

```
$> mkdir myRepo
$> cd myRepo
myRepo$> git init .
myRepo$> git submodule add https://<path/to/my/repo>.git
myRepo$> vim .gitmodules 
# change submodule url to https://<path/to/another/repo>.git
myRepo$> git submodule sync # updates my .git/config file with the new submodule url, but all my files in the submodule are still from the old url
myRepo$> git submodule sync --recursive # doesn't do anything
myRepo$> git submodule update --init --recursive # doesn't do anything either
myRepo$> rm -rf .git/modules/<mySubmodule> # tip from SO comment linked above
myRepo$> git submodule sync
fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/<mySubmodule>
```

Comment: Just a `git submodule update --init --recursive` wouldn't work (after the `git submodule sync --recursive`)?

Comment: Nope--I'm still seeing the original submodule.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336995/git-will-not-init-sync-update-new-submodules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That does seem to be annoying.  Not ideal, but the following seems to work for me

```
git submodule foreach git pull --rebase
```

Comment: Yup, that worked! Definitely not ideal but I'll take it. Can you explain your answer a bit more before I accept it? Also, were you able to replicate my problem?

Comment: I do see the same behavior with Git 2.1.1.  I am honestly not sure if it is 'expected' or a bug.  Submodules have always been somewhat hokey.  As to why it works - it causes git to go into the submodule and do a fetch (which in my case translated to a forced branch again - again, not sure why).

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky- You might want to open up a new question with some more details.  Regards